# Getting Error while inserting data in two tables in python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I want to insert data into two different tables using same database one is for loop and another is outside for loop but after inserting data into one table I am getting error.

my code

```
with connection ...
     for loop ....

            sql = "INSERT INTO user_repo (user_id, github_id, repo_id, user_connection, repo_name, contributors, total_commits, commit_by_user, created_date, last_commit) VALUES (  % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (
                        initial_details['id'],               
                        username,
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['id'] ,
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['owner'] ,
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['name'],
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['contributors'],
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['total_commits'],
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['commit_by_user'],
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['created_at'] ,
                        all_repo_data[(repo['name'])]['updated_at'],
            ))
       sql = "INSERT INTO initialdetails (github_id, name, email, user_id, location, followers, following,total_commits,total_stars,total_repos) VALUES ( % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s, % s)"
       cursor.execute(sql, (initial_details['username'],
                     initial_details['name'],
                     initial_details['email'],
                     initial_details['id'],
                     initial_details['location'],
                     initial_details['followers'],
                     initial_details['following'],
                     Total_commits_of_user,
                     total_stars,
                     total_repos,))
      connection.commit()
```

the error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\I8Labs\githubData.py", line 210, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, (initial_details['username'],
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in execute
    while self.nextset():
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 96, in nextset
    return self._nextset(False)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 83, in _nextset
    conn = self._get_db()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 65, in _get_db
    raise err.ProgrammingError("Cursor closed")
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: Cursor closed
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the cursor? The error suggests the cursor doesn’t have a valid db connection. You should be able to do consecutive executes with the same cursor, according to this example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html There’s also an `executemany` function which might help here.

Comment: @DS_London no I have a valid db connection that's how I am able to make insertion into first table but not able to insert into second table